# copy and paste object ID to one drive to another

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, drivers, shape-keys

so i'm working on a rig that has a lot of drivers and every driver needs a object ID to function
the problem is that i need to asign my rig to every driver manually

[image]

there is a easiest way to do this? like seriously it needs to be a way like when you link the materias to one object to another but i only need the object not the expression and everything else, only the object, once a select my armature the bones are automatically identified so there is no need for that extra step. Thank you for reading

Comment: well....you could use python... ;)

Comment: There is very little punctuation in your question, and it made it difficult to understand exactly what is driving what. However, I thankfully have successfully applied multiple drivers for something using python, so if you clarify what you were trying to drive, I can work on the code.

Comment: hey thank you for you response, every driver you see in the screenshot needs my armature to function, as you can see in the second screenshot there is this red box that needs a object (in this case my armature). as far as i know i need to assign my armature to every driver one by one and is very tedious task so i was wondering if there's a easiest way to do this. the drivers are part of a character. i can give you my blend file if you want so you can see what i mean